# Change attributes of change-set from command line

Tags: version-control, aegis

I tried using `aegis -change_attributes` to change the brief_description of my current change set but it didn't work.

```
aegis -change_attributes description="test"
```

What should I do to make this work?

EDIT: The command I was looking for was

```
aegis -change_attributes brief_description="$DESC";
```

Comment: I figured this out a while back. The above command is correct if you want to set the extensive description. If one wants to just set the brief description "aegis -change_attributes brief_description="$DESC"" has to be used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since no answer was given (for quite some time) I'm adding the solution I gave in the comments, as the anser:

The above command is correct if you want to set the extensive description. If one wants to just set the brief description "aegis -change_attributes brief_description="$DESC"" has to be used